# Возвращается пустой список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

При исполнении кода(ниже) в самом конце команда  возвращает пустой список, а должен быть набранный пользователем текст.

```py
while True:

    Text = list(input(' Введите текст (Только буквы, даже без знаков препинания)'))

    IntermediateCipheredText = Text

    CountSymbols0 = 0

    while True:

        if IntermediateCipheredText == []:

            break

        CountSymbols0 += 1

        del IntermediateCipheredText[0]

    print(Text)
```

Comment: Во-первых, с чего бы, если обе переменные ссылаются на один список? Во-вторых, кто научил вас плохому? Почему не просто `symbols_count = len(text)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не должен. Благодаря строке

```py
IntermediateCipheredText = Text
```

переменные `IntermediateCipheredText` и `Text` **ссылаются** на один и тот же список, который Вы в дальнейшем опустошаете. Если Вы хотите в `IntermediateCipheredText` получить копию списка `Text`, то воспользуйтесь

```py
IntermediateCipheredText = Text.copy()
```

---

P.S. получить кол-во элементов в контейнере (строка, список, кортеж и т.д.) можно с помощью

```py
CountSymbols0 = len(Text)
```

И приводить к списку вовсе не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Имя `IntermediateCipheredText` ссылается на тот же список, что и `Text`.

Если уж очень нужен такой код, скопируйте список:

```py
IntermediateCipheredText = Text.copy()
```

---

Причём посмотрите, этот код проще и несёт тот же смысл, что и данный вами:

```py
Text = input(' Введите текст (Только буквы, даже без знаков препинания)')

CountSymbols0 = len(Text)

print(Text)
```